# How can I get the `Suggestion` of PowerShell's Get-Command in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

If I create a file called "dir.exe" and run PowerShell command `Get-Command dir -Type Application`, I get and error because `dir` is not an application (although that file exists):

```
gcm : The term 'dir' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ (gcm dir -Type Application)
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dir:String) [Get-Command], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand


Suggestion [3,General]: The command dir was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\dir". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

Notice the `Suggestion` at the bottom: `Suggestion [3,General]: The command dir was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\dir". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.`

I'm trying to catch that suggestion in my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Helpers.Tests {
    [TestClass]
    public class PowerShellRunner_Tests {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetCommand_Test() {
            // create file called "dir.exe" to see how PowerShell handles
            // "Get-Command dir -Type Application":
            File.Create("dir.exe").Dispose();               

            using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create()) {
                powerShell.AddCommand("get-command")
                    .AddArgument("dir")
                    .AddParameter("Type", CommandTypes.Application.ToString());

                // run "Get-Command dir -Type Application":
                CommandInfo commandInfo = powerShell.Invoke<CommandInfo>().FirstOrDefault();

                // get the error:
                ErrorRecord error = powerShell.Streams.Error.FirstOrDefault();

                // emit the "Suggestion":
                Trace.WriteLine(error.ErrorDetails.RecommendedAction);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However `error.ErrorDetails` is `null`. How can I get that `Suggestion`?

(I'm trying to get the behavior of `where.exe` but without the hassle of running a whole process for that).

Comment: `Get-Command` works the same way as `where.exe`.  It scans `$Env:PATH` directories for files.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, not exactly. `Get-Command` returns also internal commands, like `dir` (an `Alias`), which maps to `Get-ChildItem` (a `Cmdlet`). `where.exe` will not show internal commands like `dir`.

Comment: @mklement0, I wish... but it doesn't. In the example I posted, `where.exe` indeed returns the full-path of `dir.exe`, while `gcm -Type Application dir` doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the end goal is to **emulate `where.exe`'s behavior**, try the following:

```
(Get-Command -Type Application .\dir, dir -ErrorAction Ignore).Path
```

<sup>Note the use of `-Type Application` to limit results to executables and exclude PowerShell-internal commands such as function and aliases.</sup>

This will look in the current directory *first*, as `where.exe` does.
Give a mere *name* such as `dir`, `Get-Command` doesn't look in the current directory, because PowerShell does not permit invoking executables located in the current directory by *name only* - for security reasons; using relative path `.\`, however, makes `Get-Command` find such an executable.

From `cmd.exe`, however - whose behavior `where.exe` assumes - invoking a current-directory-only `dir.exe` with just `dir` (by name only) works fine.

If the output is just *one* path, and that path is a file in the *current directory*, you can infer that the `dir` executable exists *only* in the current directory, which is the condition under which PowerShell emits the suggestion to use an explicit path on invocation.

```
$fullPaths = (Get-Command -Type Application .\dir, dir -ErrorAction Ignore).Path
$emitSuggestion = $fullPaths.Count -eq 1 -and 
                  (Test-Path ('.\' + (Split-Path -Leaf $fullPaths[0]))
```

<sup>Note: Strictly speaking, you'd also to have rule out the case where the current directory just so happens be one that is listed in `$env:PATH`:

`$env:PATH -split ';' -ne '' -notcontains (Split-Path -Parent $fullPaths[0])`</sup>

You can report that to your C# code by writing a custom version of the suggestion to the error stream via `Write-Error`, or, preferably, to the *warning* stream, with `Write-Warning`.

---

To use the above commands via the PowerShell SDK, it's simplest to use the `.AddScript()` method; e.g.:

```
powerShell.AddScript("(Get-Command -Type Application .\dir, dir -ErrorAction Ignore).Path");
```

---

**As for capturing or silencing PowerShell's suggestions:**

Unfortunately, **you cannot gain access to suggestions programmatically** (written as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.1.0):

Using the PowerShell SDK, as you do, involves the PowerShell [*default host*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/hostifaces/DefaultHost.cs), which fundamentally doesn't emit suggestions.

It is only the [*console host*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHost.cs), as used in console (terminal) windows that emits suggestions, but even there suggestions are printed *directly to the screen*, bypassing PowerShell's system of output streams.

In short: **Suggestions only show in *console windows* (terminals), and can only be *viewed*, not captured there.**

---

A quick demonstration of the behavior of suggestions in a console window (assumes Windows, with a file named `dir.exe` in the current dir and not also in `$env:PATH`):

```
PS> & { try { Get-Command dir.exe } catch {} } *>$null

Suggestion [3,General]: The command dir.exe was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\dir.exe". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

As you can see, despite the attempt to suppress *all* output (`*>$null`), the suggestion still printed to the screen, which also implies that **you cannot *capture* suggestions.**

However, **there *is* a way to *silence* suggestions, namely with `-ErrorAction Ignore`** (PSv3+); by contrast, with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` the suggestion still prints(!):

```
PS> & { try { Get-Command dir.exe -ErrorAction Ignore } catch {} } *>$null
# no output
```